# Finding gradient of perpendicular lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus, slope

What will be the gradient of a vertical line and a horizontal line? Both are perpendicular to each other, and I know the product of their gradients must be $-1$, but that is for slanted lines. What if the lines are parallel to the axes? Horizontal lines have zero gradient and vertical have infinity, so what will be there product? Also, can you tell why perpendicular lines have to have $-1$ gradient?

Comment: Vertical lines don't have a well-defined gradient, so the rule that perpendicular lines gradients multiply to -1 is not valid in the case of these lines.

Comment: so what will be there gradient?

Comment: $\infty$ for the vertical line, $0$ for the horizontal line. If you consider an almost horizontal line of very small slope $\epsilon$, then the almost vertical perpendicular line to that has a slope $\frac{-1}{\epsilon}$ so their product is $-1$ and now you can take the limit as $\epsilon$ goes to 0.